# asp.mcv how to convert string into boolean flag

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm trying too make a login page. But when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> the page this line gives an error:

```
flag = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Login.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
namespace LoginFormApp.Models
{
public class Login
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required")] 
    [Display(Name = "Username")]   
    public string username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string password { get; set; }
    public bool checkUser(string username, string password) 
    { 
        bool flag = false;
        string connString =        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabaseEntities"].ConnectionString    ; 
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from Login     where username='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "'", conn);
            flag = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            return flag;
        }
    } 
}
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@model LoginFormApp.Models.Login
@{
 Layout = null;
}
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>DNDB Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin:0 auto; text-align: center; border: 2px; border-style:   solid; width:400px;background-color:lightgrey">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.username)</td> 
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.username)</td> 
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.username)</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.password)</td> 
                <td>@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.password)</td> 
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.password)</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    @ViewBag.Message
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

show.cshtml

```
@model LoginFormApp.Models.Login
@{
Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Show</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h3> Hi! @Model.username</h3> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Homecontroller.cs

```
using LoginFormApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace LoginFormApp.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult Index(Login login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            if (login.checkUser(login.username, login.password)) 
            {
                return View("Show", login); 
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Username or Password";
                return View(); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View(); 
        }
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it wrongly, 
**ExecuteScalar()** always returns the value of the first column, so in your case it returns the total counts which cannot be direclty convert to boolean.

```
int totalCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
flag = totalCount > 0;
```

Comment: chaged it too this:    conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from Login where username='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "'", conn);
                int totalCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                flag = totalCount > 0;
                return flag;          Now the line:  int totalCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());  Gives an error

Comment: Do you want all the code too see what is my mistake?

Comment: Can you check what is the value of cmd.ExecuteScalar()

Comment: But you didnt changed,

  flag = Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            return flag;

with my code.

Comment: When I add your code, the program says this line is wrong:  int totalCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()); My total code now is:      conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select count(*) from Login where username='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "'", conn);
                int totalCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                flag = totalCount > 0;
                return flag;

Comment: Check you have Login table in the database?

Comment: Actually its an sql exception saying Login table is not found in the specified connection.

Comment: Is there anyway I can chat with you or add you if I have any questions in the future?

Comment: You can use StackOverflow, so that these questions can be useful to others as well

Comment: Btw, you know an easy way for me too add a logout button? (new to programming so its kinda hard for me.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
flag = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar() == 1;
```

Comment: I added all my code, that includes your line. It gives your line as an error.

Comment: @Marijn - What kind of error ? Syntactically it is correct; but a type conversion error will occur if cmd.ExecuteScalar throws itsself an exception or returns an object that is not an int. Without a stacktrace this is hard to tell.

Comment: @Marijn - the SQL server returns an error that your SQL statement cannot be executed. It happens in this line, because ExecuteScalar sends the command and notifies you about this error by this exception. The datatable "Login" is not known. Perhaps the table has not been created or the spelling is wrong.

Comment: Its fixed.Thanks anyway